# create multiple network plots by edge attribute

Tags: r, igraph

I have a igraph network object with a number of edge attributes. One edge attribute classifies type of network according to number (e.g. 1 = friendship, 2 = advice). I want to plot each type of network separately. However, I do not want to create separate sub-graphs. I want to maintain the same layout for all network types, using just one igraph network object. How to do this is not obvious to me in the iGraph documentation. Can somebody help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no direct way to do that in `igraph`. And that makes sense because those are *attributes*; i.e., something additional rather than a standard way to specify an edge type. Hence, I think one good option is simply altering the set of edges while plotting a graph as in the following example:

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_ring(10) %>%
  set_edge_attr("weight", value = 1:10) %>%
  set_edge_attr("color", value = "red")

plot(g %>% delete_edges(which(edge_attr(g)$weight > 5)))
plot(g %>% delete_edges(which(edge_attr(g)$weight <= 5)))
```

Comment: Another way would be to plot graphs as heat maps, I suppose.

Comment: @user2995175, true. I'd say using `plot` is more for the case when the interest in each specific network alone is big enough, while heatmap would help to compare the distribution of edges between the two.

Answer (score 1):

if you plot the graph twice and set the same `set.seed()` before each plot, the layout should be the same. Then you could make edges transparent/visible depending on the edges you want to show.